# SQL Server query execution plan for stored procedure references table that does not exist in code

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

I have a graphical query plan for a stored procedure. In one part of the procedure the plan makes reference to a table (not a view or function) that doesn't exist within the stored procedure. I've gone through the stored procedure line by line, checked tables to see if triggers had been defined on them and still I can't find the table name the query plan is making a reference to.

Has anyone ever come across this? Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: The table is likely referenced from a view of function that is in your query (directly or indirectly).  Views and inline table functions do not show up in the query plan, they get translated into their component table references.

Comment: I've gone through all the views and functions within the stored procedure and looked at the definition of each. I still see no reference to the table name. I think I am going to have to let this one go and chalk it up to some sort of bug. Thanks for the info.

Comment: It's probably indirect.  Try using *View Dependencies* from that table back to your stored procedure.  It can get quite deep sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same thing with my sql server, and turns out the speed is alot faster when it does reference the table that doesn't exists in the code as compared to the query plan that doesn't reference it, so I just let it go